# Can't make unit tests for reading parquet files created from protobuf messages

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, parquet

I wrote a parquet file from a protobuf message as such

```
ProtobufData model = ProtobufData.get();

Schema schema = model.getSchema(ExampleMessage.class);

Configuration conf = new Configuration();

ParquetWriter<ExampleMessage> writer = AvroParquetWriter
    .<ExampleMessage>builder(new Path(parquetFile))
    .withConf(conf)
    .withDataModel(model)
    .withSchema(schema)
    .build();

for (T object : objects) {
    writer.write(object);
}

writer.close();
```

I got the above code from here: https://github.com/rdblue/parquet-avro-protobuf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/ProtobufToParquet.java

I have verified that the parquet files are being created as expected using a third party parquet file viewer.
Now, I would also like to create a unit test that verifies the creation of parquet files with the correct dummy data. For this, I am trying to read the newly created parquet file within Java and asserting that the data exists as expected. For this, I have written the following piece of code.

```
ParquetReader<ExampleMessage> reader = AvroParquetReader
        .<ExampleMessage>builder(dataFile)
        .withDataModel(new ReflectData(ExampleMessage.class.getClassLoader()))
        .disableCompatibility()
        .withConf(conf)
        .build();

List<ExampleMessage> recordsList = new ArrayList<>();

ExampleMessage record;
while ((record = reader.read()) != null) {
    recordsList.add(record);
}
```

This keeps throwing the error that GenericRecord cannot be converted to ExampleMessage on the following line, no matter what I try.

```
while((record = reader.read()) != null) {
```

I have tried using ProtoParquetReader, GenericDatumReader, DecoderFactory and a tonne of different things I found online and chatGPT recommended but nothing seemed to work.

All I want is to read the parquet file and get data as variables of the original type, i.e. ExampleMessage here.